# could someone point me to a reference on the Lie-Trotter-Chernoff formula?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, operator-theory

I am trying to understand the Lie-Trotter-Chernoff formula in the context of differential equations, in particular concerning the flux of a vector field. On my textbook there is only a vague reference and I'd like to know more about it but I'm quite a beginner in the field.
Could somebody please point me to a basic reference covering the subject?

Comment: I'm assuming $+50$ is too less for you mercenaries! :)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this link....

https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01697972

http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022123610002934